# How to fire rotation event of a UIViewcontroller view inside a UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, rotation

I have 1 UIViewController with a UIScrollView as view.
For each page of this scrollview I alloc 1 UIViewControllers and I add his view inside this Scrollview.

When I am going to rotate the device, rotation event in the sub viewcontrollers (that ones that have their views inside the scrollview) doesn't fire...

can anyone help me? thanks :)

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main ViewController method `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

Call

```
[yourSubViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
```